# Print the value of an \addtocounter as it is added

Tags: counters

In the following example, I want the resulting pdf to show the values of `300` and `500`, but they do not print.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\newcounter{fund}
\newcommand{\fund}[1]{\addtocounter{fund}{#1}}

My first funding was worth \$\fund{300}.

My second funding was worth \$\fund{500}.

Thus, in total, my funding was \$\thefund.

\end{document}
```

Is there a way I can print this value without the redundant:

```
My first funding was worth \$300. \fund{300}
```

Thanks.

Comment: There's no command within `\fund` that prints the current value of the counter! Either use `#1` for the increment value to be printed or `\thefund` for the total counter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure this is meant (and I don't recommend it anyway), but here is the definition of `\fund` that adds an increment value and prints this value of the `fund` counter.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{fund}
\newcommand{\fund}[1]{\addtocounter{fund}{#1}#1}

\begin{document}


My first funding was worth \$\fund{300}.

My second funding was worth \$\fund{500}.

Thus, in total, my funding was \$\thefund.

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update**

Here's a slightly different version:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{incfund}

\renewcommand{\theincfund}{\textdollar{}\arabic{incfund}}

\newcounter{fund}
\newcommand{\fund}[1]{%
  \setcounter{incfund}{#1}\theincfund%
  \addtocounter{fund}{#1}%
}

\begin{document}


My first funding was worth \fund{300}.

My second funding was worth \fund{500}.

Thus, in total, my funding was \textdollar\thefund.

\end{document}
```

Comment: This works! Why don't you recommend it?

Comment: @CephBirk: It mixes 'computation' and output. And you can't use this for $100.50$, for example